# Alternative for tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing that works on embedded system (ARM6)

Tags: resize, tensorflow-lite, linear-interpolation, tpu, google-coral

I use the following model for audio classification:

```
model = models.Sequential([
  layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
  preprocessing.Resizing(64, 64), 
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding="same"), 
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'), 
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'), 
  layers.Dropout(0.25),
  layers.Flatten(), 
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(0.5),
  layers.Dense(2),  
])
```

This works fine on a CPU. Now I would like to run the trained model on a TPU (Coral USB Accelerator via Raspberry Pi Zero (ARM6)). The [edge TPU compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/) which must be used to run a model on the Coral does not accept [tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Resizing) (third line in code snippet). The edge TPU compiler does only accept a subset of TensorFlow lite functions. Therefore I am now looking for an alternative to resize my 624x129x1 spectrogram to 64x64x1 as a preprocessing step outside of models.Sequential(). Unfortunately, Tensorflow and PyTorch do not work on the RPI0. Therefore I cannot use these libraries and am looking for an alternative to preprocess the spectrogram to the right size.
Any help or advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, you can install the TensorFlow on raspberry pi armv6 boards. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. Here is even TF 2.4: https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases